# AsyncTask <Map<String, List<Object>>

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, hashmap

I am trying to do an asynctask with the data being queried and returned from the database being in the form:

```
Map<String, List<Object>>
```

I tried starting the asynctask like this:

```
public class GetIndividualAlarmsFromDataBase extends AsyncTask <Map<String, List<Object>>
```

which I think is correct because I don't get any errors beside implement methods.

But when I go to implement the methods I am doing them incorrectly because it says method does not override superclass.

I tried to create the do in background like this:

```
@Override
protected Map<String, List<Object> doInBackground(Map<String, List<Object>> map) {
    return null;
}
```

and the on post execute like this:

```
@Override
public void onPostExecute(Map<String, List<Object>> map) {
}
```

What is wrong with my syntax and how would I implement this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: The `doInBackground` one definitely won't compile, because it has malformed return type declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define parameters for Params, Progress, Result

```
public abstract class AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
```

--

```
public static class GetIndividualAlarmsFromDataBase extends AsyncTask<Map<String, List<Object>>,Void ,Map<String, List<Object>>> {

    @Override
    protected Map<String, List<Object>> doInBackground(Map<String, List<Object>>[] maps) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) `AsyncTask` takes 3 generic parameters:

> An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params, Progress and Result

You only provided "Params", so "Progress" and "Result" are `Object` by default.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Object Class to qualify **AsyncTask Params, Progress, Result**

```
 public class GetIndividualAlarmsFromDataBase extends AsyncTask <Map ,Void,Map>{
    @Override
    protected Map doInBackground(Map... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Map map) {
        super.onPostExecute(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As per  developer gide [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) 
AsyncTask syntax is like this

`public abstract class AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`

so your AsyncTask look like

```
public class GetIndividualAlarmsFromDataBase extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Map<String,List<Object>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

for the parameters of AsyncTask in simple terms :

```
extends AsyncTask<<Map<String, List<Object>>, Integer, Map<String, List<Object>>>{}
```

- 1st is a parameter of doInBackGround method,
- 2nd is the parameter of onProgressUpdate method,
- 3rd is important, which is return type of doInBackGoround method, and a Post result to onPostExecute method.

so now your class looks like :

```
public class GetIndividualAlarmsFromDataBase extends AsyncTask<Map<String, List<Object>>, Integer, Map<String, List<Object>>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, List<Object>> doInBackground(Map<String, List<Object>>[] maps) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Map<String, List<Object>> maps) {
        super.onPostExecute(maps);
    }
}
```